# Cannot connect to dockerized SQL Server using invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I don't have `sqlcmd.exe` nor `sqlps` for some bizarre reason, even though I installed the `sqlserver` module from `PSGallery`, so I'm not sure if that's screwing me over or not.

The main problem I have is that I just can't seem to be able to SQL Server using `invoke-sqlcmd`, even though I was able to connect to it with SSMS.

This is the SQL Server container:

```
e1cfd6032947   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   21 hours ago   Up 21 hours   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp                        mystifying_keller
```

I connected to it through SSMS, but for some reason it just doesn't work through powershell 5 with `invoke-sqlcmd` applet, the annoying thing is that it doesn't even give me an error:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 127.0.0.1:1433 -Database db1
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1:1433' -Database db1
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1,1433' -Database db1
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1,1433' -Database db1 -Username 'SA' -Password 'yourStrong(!)Password'
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1,1433' -Database db1 -Username 'SA' -Password 'yourStrong(!)Password' -Query "PRINT 'This is output'"
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1,1433' -Database db1 -Username 'SA' -Password 'yourStrong(!)Password' -Query "SELECT * FROM Users;"
PS C:\>
```

(Yes, db1 is a test db that I created in SSMS just in case a database is actually necessary).

I have literally no clue what I'm doing wrong, or why it's not working :/

Comment: Your forgot to include a query to run: `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1:1433' -Database db1 -Query "SELECT @@SERVERNAME;"`

Comment: I did use a query, but it didn't return anything and I assumed something was wrong, not that the table was empty.... I'm an idiot

Comment: One good way of avoiding this would be to use queries that use the system databases, such as `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`, `SELECT @@VERSION` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The table I tried doing this to was empty, hence no results returned:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1,1433' -Database db1 -Username 'SA' -Password 'yourStrong(!)Password' -Query "SELECT * FROM Users;"

After adding data in it, I get this, which is all good:
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '127.0.0.1, 1433' -Database db1 -Username 'SA' -Password 'yourStrong(!)Password' -Query "SELECT * FROM Users;"

id name
-- ----
 1 Me
 2 You
 3 They
```